# Python warnings

Tags: python, dataframe, transform

Input:myfile

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

```
amountFile=pd.read_excel("myfile")
amountFile['total_amount']=amountFile.groupby('ID')["item_amount"].transform('sum')
amountFile.to_excel('file location')
```

above is my code to calculate new total amount column by taking sum of item amount in each item. It works fine but I am getting warning ,so I am afraid is it a problem.

see the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  amountFile['total_amount']=amountFile['total_amount']=amountFile.groupby('ID')["item_amount"].transform('sum')
C:/Users/JasnaRaghavan/PycharmProjects/PobImportScript/testReconsile.py:40: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code but didn't get the same error. If you're getting that warning though, it means Pandas can't guarantee whether you are working on the column itself (i.e. a slice of the DataFrame) or a copy of the slice.

You could try using `.loc` to access the column instead. Your code would look something like this:

```
amountFile.loc[:, 'total_amount'] = amountFile.groupby('ID')["item_amount"].transform('sum')
```

Comment: Ok thank you..  Actually I splitted a particular dataframe into two, among that this amount file is one dataframe. Is it that the reason?. Copy of the slice means?. I am new to python sorry for this small questions.

Comment: Possibly. Not sure what your preceding code is, but maybe try adding ```.copy()``` e.g. ```amountFile = your_first_dataframe["some_column_name"].copy()``` .